# How does Mailchimp's Social Pro work?

Tags: api, social-networking, mailchimp

I've recently used social pro from mailchimp on a site...

http://www.mailchimp.com/features/social-pro/

and was shocked to find the amount of information it can gether online using just a few user details. How does it work? What APIs does it use, and how could I recreate a similar experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they say something about http://www.rapleaf.com (and it provides API). I am not sure that it is the only source, but worth checking.

> Sync your lists with social and
>   demographic data from Rapleaf to
>   enhance your subscriber profiles

Answer (score 1):

Probably a combination of many data sources. At minimum, tracing gravatars probably provide a lot of that data, and you can infer a lot from backlinks and rel=me as well.

Comment: I see, i've authenticated an account with them an can now see what data they are able to access. I can see that they have found twitter, flickr, myspace and interestingly a plaxo account (a service I do not use) They also say they have publicly available census data, and my job description!? Scary!